# Is function dereferencing possible in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
function a() {
   return 1;
}


a()++;
```

I get an error, is this just not going to be possible in JS?

[image]

What I want is to get the value 2.

Comment: The operands of the increment and decrement operators must be valid l-values (things that can appear on the left side of an `=` operator).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're attempting to increment a constant, which makes no sense.

In essence, you've written this:

```
1++;
```

or

```
1 = 1 + 1
```

This doesn't work in JavaScript or *any* language, as far as I know. Certainly Ruby, PHP and C++ will all similarly die if you attempt to do this.

If you want to arrive at the value `2`, you want straight addition:

```
a() + 1
```

Note that function dereferencing works just fine when you're not attempting to modify a constant value:

```
function a() { return [1, 2, 3]; }

a()[1]; // 2

function b() { return {name: "bob"} }

b().name; // "bob"
```

Answer (score 2):

*No.* The issue is that `++` (like `+=`) only applies to expressions of the [Reference Specification Type](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7).

That is, `++` is *only* valid when used with "a variable or property expression".

> The Reference type is used to explain the behaviour of such operators as delete, typeof, and the assignment operators [including `++`, `+=`, etc]. For example, the left-hand operand of an assignment is expected to produce a reference [specification type expression].

```
var x
x++       // variable
          // same as x = x + 1, when used as statement
((x))++   // totally legal, still an RST-expression

var o = {p: 0}
o.p++     // property
          // same as o.p = o.p + 1, when used as statement

// while odd, still legal as the ++ applies to an RST-expression
var q
((q = {p: 0}).p)++  // q.p == 1, after
```

However, a function call expression *never* yields an RST-value and thus fails. It is *not* a SyntaxError, and the production is *allowed*, but the type is wrong which results in a run-time ReferenceError exception.

```
// (modified to show it is a run-time exception not related to parsing)
function f () {
   f()++  // whoops!
          // same failure as f() = f() + 1
}
f();
```

Functions merely return values (that result from evaluating expressions), but there is *no* assignable expression in JavaScript which yields an RST-value - the aforementioned operators "consume" the RST-expression and evaluate to a non-RST value.

---

A variation of the original question [*is* possible in C++](http://ideone.com/ZnImni), which supports creating explicit references. However, in ECMAScript, RST's are primarily used when describing "l-value behavior" but are not otherwise exposed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x;
int& func() {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    func()++;
    cout << x << endl;
    func()++;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would care to show an example of doing that in C++?

Comment: @RPM That's no different than JavaScript, or any language where you can return a reference. They all let you modify the returned reference without first assigning it to a local variable.

Comment: @meagar so we can do this in JS?

Comment: @RPM Modify returned references inline? Yes. Increment a return value? No. There is no way of passing/returning references to primary types in JavaScript, only composite types: Arrays and objects. Neither of these can be incremented.

Comment: @meagar It's very much different! JavaScript *does not return or pass "references" in this sense*. JavaScript returns and passes values. The fact that an *implementation* uses "pointers" or "references" to implement such behavior should not be drawn into this particular usage, *especially* since it overload the terms! The original question is about *references* (or perhaps just misidentification of "ReferenceError" error), not about call-by-sharing / call-by-value "of-the-reference" semantics.

Comment: @meagar I think your answer does a good job of showing the latter, but that's not related to "references" (excluding that such is a common *implementation detail*), merely that a function invocation results in a value/object can be used immediately.