# Applying ++ operator to return value of function causes error

Tags: javascript

I have to following little test page:

```
var getNum = function(){
    return 5;
};
var y = getNum()++; // This causes an error.
document.write("y = " + y);
```

which causes this error in firefox 27.01:

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
var y = getNum()++;
```

If I change the line:

```
var y = getNum()++;
```

for

```
var y = getNum() + 1;
```

then I get no error. Would anyone happen to know why getNum()++ is not allowed? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I take it I was unwittingly trying to do something like 5 = 6

Answer (score 2):

tldr: It doesn't make sense.

The `++` operator (like `+=`) *only* applies to expressions of the [Reference Specification Type](http://es5.github.io/x8.html#x8.7). That is, `++` is *only* valid when used with "a variable or property expression".

> The Reference type is used to explain the behaviour of such operators as delete, typeof, and the assignment operators [including ++, +=, etc]. For example, the left-hand operand of an assignment is expected to produce a reference [specification type expression].

This is how JavaScript can *assign* a value back to the appropriate variable/property. A run-time ReferenceError is thrown when such an assignment cannot be made, such as when trying to apply `++` to the result of a function call or literal expression.

(The above summary is from [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185092/is-function-dereferencing-possible-in-javascript/22185599#22185599).)

Comment: +1 Another way to view it is as [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3) says: it can only be applied to a valid *LeftHandSideExpression*. The ++ operator evaluates the expression, increments it by one, then **assigns the value back to the expression**. So it can only operate on something that is valid on the left hand side of an assignment expression, where any sort of literal is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're essentially writing `y = 5++`.

Comment: Thanks. I take it 5++ really means 5 = 5 + 1 as opposed to replace the 5 with a 6.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `++` equals to `+= 1`.

So:

```
var y = getNum()++;
```

same as:

```
var y = 5 += 1;
```