# Unable to append to table within javascript. Error: Cannot assign to a function result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using ajax to get an item from a web API and then trying to assign attributes of that item to a table:

```
 function find() {
        var id = $('#contentID').val();
        $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
            .done(function (data) {
             fillTable(data);
                                })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#content').text('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }


    function fillTable(item) {
      document.getElementById("mybody") += "<td id = \"td1\" runat=\"server\">" + item.contentType + "</td> <td id=\"td2\" runat=\"server\">" + item.contentID + "</td></tr>";
    }
```

and I have this table within my html:

```
 <table id="example" class="responstable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-th="Driver details"><span>Timestamp</span></th>
                <th>Content Type</th>
                <th>Task Name</th>
                <th>Task Version</th>
                <th>Task State</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="mybody" runat="server">
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

I know I'm getting the JSON object back because I printed its attributes to the screen and they printed fine. I don't understand why javascript won't append them into the table.

Comment: You can't do this: `document.getElementById("mybody") +=`. Try `document.getElementById("mybody").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mybody").innerHTML + ...`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737896/jquery-cannot-assign-to-a-function-result

Comment: @christian314159 thank you, that was the issue, careless mistake.

Comment: The error exists for the same reason [as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069985/applying-operator-to-return-value-of-function-causes-error/23070212#23070212) (albeit with an explicit assignment, not an increment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment *to* the result of a function call doesn't make sense and is prohibited, with a run-time exception.

The `=` (assignment) operator, and derivatives like `+=`, *requires* that the left-hand side of the operator is an expressions of the [Reference Specification Type](http://es5.github.io/x8.html#x8.7). That is, `lhs = e` is only valid when used with "a variable or property expression" as `lhs`.

> The Reference type is used to explain the behaviour of such operators as delete, typeof, and the assignment operators [including =, +=, etc]. For example, the left-hand operand of an assignment is expected to produce a reference [specification type expression].

This is how JavaScript can assign a value back to the appropriate variable/property. A run-time error is thrown when such an assignment cannot be made, such as when trying to use a function-call on the left-hand side of the `=` operator.

(This is an adaption of my answer dealing with [++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069985/applying-operator-to-return-value-of-function-causes-error).)

---

This particular instance could be solved by the following which *satisfies* the above stated requirement because `innerHTML` is a *property*.

```
 var elm = document.getElementById("mybody");
 elm.innerHTML += "the new stuff";
```

(But, even better is to use proper DOM manipulation, not HTML mangling.)